# Is table-layout: fixed as performant as decoupled tables?

Tags: html, css, extjs, html-table, gxt

I've seen that some frameworks (e.g. `extJs` or `Gxt2`) render their grids not with one large `table` but with a structure where each row itself is a new `table`. I assume this to improve performance with large grids because the browser won't have to wait for the whole table to be calculated before painting it.

Now I stumbled upon other frameworks (like `Gxt3`) that use one large table but with `table-layout: fixed`. How does this approach compare to the "decoupled" (sorry for not having a better term here, maybe there exists one) table described above? Does this have the same performance benefit?

**Examples**

*Standard table*

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*"Decoupled"*

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot say anything about performance, but the first and foremost problem of decoupled tables is a bug in Chrome with browser zoom and subpixels, which I have reported here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=717469